# JavaScript: создание массива внутри объекта

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

Объясните матчасть, пож-та, а именно:

Почему нельзя объявить массив внутри объекта следующим образом:

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent',
    // Обратите внимание на "var"
    interests: var myArray = [music, photo, true, 8]
};
```

При том, что объявление массива внутри объекта следующим образом является
корректным:

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent',
    interests: myArray = [music, photo, true, 8]
};
```

?

Comment: Потому что синтаксис такой. Какого эффекта вы хотите добиться с `var`?

Comment: Эффект тот же - простое создание массива внутри объекта. Я не против, что синтаксис принуждает это делать, мне важно понять - почему делать нужно именно так? Почему без var? Просто, чтобы в голове отложилось.

Comment: js же явно говорит, что ожидает выражение, а получил ключевое слово.

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Когда Вы пишете вот так:

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent',
    interests: myArray = [music, photo, true, 8]
};
```

Вот что происходит в этой (`interests: myArray = [music, photo, true, 8]`) строке:

1. Создается глобальная переменная `window.myArray`
2. Создается `Array(music, photo, true, 8)`
3. Переменной `window.myArray` присваевается значение массива
4. `myObject['interests']` становится равен `window.myArray`

В таких случаях лучше делать так:

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent',
    interests: [music, photo, true, 8]
};
```

Либо если нужно создать этот массив зарание лучше сделать так:

```
var myArray = [music, photo, true, 8];
var myObject = {
    name: 'Eduardo',
    type: 'Most excellent',
    interests: myArray
};
```

То действие не может корректно обработать компилятор. Но, даже если бы работал, то выражение `var myArray = [music, photo, true, 8]` имело бы значение `undefined`.